# Property stronger than $T_1$ and weaker than regularity

Tags: gn.general-topology

Recently I got interested in the following property of topological spaces:

$(X,\mathcal{T})$ satisfies (P) if the following holds:

For any nonempty closed subsets $F$ and $G$ with $F\ne G$, there are closed subsets $F'\subseteq F$ and $G'\subseteq G$ satisfying the following conditions:

- $F'$ has nonempty interior in $F$,
- $G'$ has nonempty interior in $G$,
- $F'\cap G'=\varnothing$.

It is not difficult to show that regularity implies property (P). Moreover, for $T_0$ spaces, property (P) implies $T_1$ (this is also easily seen by letting $x\ne y$ such that $\overline{\{x\}}\subseteq \overline{\{y\}}$, $\overline{\{y\}}\not\subseteq \overline{\{x\}}$, choosing $F=\overline{\{y\}}$ and $G=\overline{\{x\}}$, and deriving a contradiction.).

In view of this situation, I was wondering if this property appears in the literature or if anyone knows any relation to other well-known properties.

Comment: Notation G for open sets is annoying. Instead of F and G, you may have A and B.

Comment: @WlodAA : Did you mean "notation $G$ for **closed** sets is annoying"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis, yes, of course, "notation 
 for **closed** sets is annoying" -- sorry for my misprint.

Comment: @WlodAA : I wondered, though, why a standard notation for open sets is $G$ and that for closed sets is $F$.  I mean, $F$ precedes $G$ in the alphabet, whereas opens sets are usually introduced before closed ones.

Comment: Historically, closed sets were before the open sets (I believe so). --#--#--#-- Also, notation F (for closed sets) comes from the French "Fermé"; then open G followed.

Comment: @WlodAA : Interesting. You might want to answer, with bibliographical details, the question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440625/notations-for-open-and-closed-sets

Comment: @IosifPinelis, I’ll do it just for you -- I'll copy my comment, and will add one more observation (I am not in a situation where I can do a real search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hausdorff spaces need not have this property. Consider [Bing's Countable connected Hausdorff space](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1953-0060806-9) (Example 75 in Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*); it has the property that for every pair of nonempty open sets $U$ and $V$ the closures $\overline U$ and $\overline V$ intersect. Let $U$ and $V$ be nonempty, open, and disjoint, and let $F=\overline U$ and $G=\overline V$. Let $F'$ and $G'$ be closed subsets of $F$ and $G$ respectively with non-empty relative open interior, say $F'\supseteq U'\cap F\neq\emptyset$ and $G'\supseteq G\cap V'\neq\emptyset$ for some open sets $U'$ and $V'$. Then also $U'\cap U$ and $V'\cap V$ are nonempty and $F'$ and $G'$ contain their closures, so $F'\cap G'\neq\emptyset$.
2. Urysohn spaces do have this property. In Urysohn spaces distinct points have disjoint *closed* neighbourhoods. So, assume $F\neq G$ and, wlog, take $x\in F\setminus G$ and $y\in G$. Let $U$ and $V$ be open sets with $x\in U$, $y\in V$ and $\overline U\cap\overline V=\emptyset$. Let $F'$ be the closure of $U\cap F$ and let $G'$ be the closure of $V\cap G$. These are as required.