# Notations for open and closed sets

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, ho.history-overview, notation

I am wondering why a standard notation for open sets is $G$ and that for closed sets is $F$.  I mean, $F$ precedes $G$ in the alphabet, whereas open sets are usually introduced before closed ones.

Comment: Fermé and geschlossen? (Why in different alphabets, I couldn't tell you, except that surely everyone is glad that we don't use $O$, tho' it could mean *o*pen *or* *o*uvert.)

Comment: Fermé sounds like a plausible explanation, but geschlossen means closed rather than open.

Comment: If $G$ is supposed to be used for an open set, then 'Gebiet' would be my first association.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, [whoops](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440625/notations-for-open-and-closed-sets#comment1136506_440625), I guess my abysmal French still outstrips my doubly abysmal German.  (I also [said](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440625/notations-for-open-and-closed-sets#comment1136502_440625) ‘alphabet’ when I meant ‘language’.  Not my finest philological hour!)

Comment: For the record, I'm pretty sure I have never seen an open set called $G$ (and I'm not sure about a closed set called $F$)...

Comment: Do you have a reference to a standard text where $G$ is used preferentially to denote an open set? $A$ is often used to denote a closed set because of the German 'abgeschlossen'. Similarly, $U$ for an open neighbourhood derives from the German 'Umgebung'.

Comment: I think the association with F and G is through the notion of $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ sets.

Comment: Dp you have a citation for the assertion that open sets are usually introduced before closed sets?

Comment: @bof : I think almost every more or less contemporary book on general topology (see e.g. Kelley's *General Topology* or Engelking's *General Topology*) first introduces the notion of a topology, the open sets being its members, and then the closed sets, as the complements of the open ones.

Comment: @bof, Iosif iis obviously right about the modern topology texts. In addition to classic Kelly+Engelking, let me add even more classical Eilenberg/Steenrod+Bourbaki; but also Dugundji "Topology", Fuks/Rokhlin, etc., etc. etc.

Comment: @IosifPinelis General topology?? It was a long time ago, but I learned about open and closed sets well before topology, probably in a class in "advanced calculus". I certainly don't remember whether open or closed sets came first, likely they were more or less simultaneous, and it would have been in the context of $\mathbb R^n$ or at worst metric spaces, not general topological spaces.

Comment: @bof : "General topology??" -- Yes, I think the notions of open/closed sets belong in general topology. As for calculus, I have never taken it, advanced or otherwise, and I have never taught advanced calculus. So, now I have looked at the first two advanced calculus texts that I have come across on the Internet, by R. C. Buck (3rd edition) and by A. E. Taylor and W. R. Mann (3rd edition), and they both define closed sets after open ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that @LSpice has already provided an answer in their comment (I see that Emil has added a clarification, so to speak). Mine will compliment the comment by @LSpice a little.

Historically, closed sets were before the open sets (I believe so). Kazimierz Kuratowski defined topology (of general $T_1$-spaces} via the closure operation hence the closed sets came before open sets. We are talking here about the years 1921 and 1933.

I seem to remember that also Wacław Sierpiński was introducing the closed sets before open sets. Possibly, the respecive Sierpiński's script was the first monography entirely devoted to topological spaces. Sierpiński wrote also a separate script about metric spaces from the purely metic (not topological) point of view.

Earlier, I believe, that topologists/mathematicians were talking about **neighborhoods** rather than open sets. Perhaps(?) people started to talk about open sets seriously only after the results/papers by Paul S. Urysohn (I am not a historian -- please, do double-check my vague reminiscences).

Finally, the notation F (for closed sets) comes from the French "Fermé"; then open G followed. In the old days, French and German were ruling mathematics before English.

---

---

**SOURCES:**

- Hausdorff definition of topological spaces via neighborhoods:

$\qquad$https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HausdorffAxioms.html

See also Bourbaki foundational text on General Topology, it presents the Hausdorff neighborhood axioms soon after the today standard definition via open sets.

Hausdorff gutsy topological axioms absorbed Hilbert's axioms on 2d-geometric spaces.

Comment: Thank you for politely passing over my suggestion that "geschlossen" might be a good inspiration for the name of an open set.

Comment: Even though you did compliment, I think you meant "complement".

Comment: @mathworker21, at first I DID write *complement* but the computer speller insisted on *compliment* -- and who am I to quarrel  about English?! (except for ...).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If this is not too much to ask for, do you have sources for these interesting statements?

Comment: @IosifPinelis, I'll try to add some sources tp my "Answer" but at a very slow pace, perhaps one at the time, I am truly sorry.

Comment: At the very least, Wikipedia agrees that $G_\delta$ / $F_\sigma$ are named after gebiet / fermé: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set

Comment: Hausdorff's "Mengenlehre" is readily available st srchive.org.  Starting at p. 209 he introduces neighbourhood systems axiomatically and goes on to use this to define interior points and open sets (which he calls "Gebiet") in the manner which was to become familiar.  In this vein let me point out that the Austrian mathematician  Vietoris extended this to develop the modern concepts of filter bases and nets, their convergence and compactness in the modern sense shortly afterwards (published 1919).

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: A useful reference is [*The emergence of open sets, closed sets, and limit points in analysis and topology*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086008000050) by Gregory H. Moore (2008). On p. 229 (lines 2-3) Moore observes that Lebesgue, in his 1905 descriptive set theory paper, used F (fermé) for closed sets and O (ouvert) for open sets; and on p. 237 (first sentence of Section 15) Moore observes that Hausdorff used F (fermé) for closed sets and G (gebiet) for open sets.

Comment: @KevinCasto : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @terceira : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro : Thank you for your comment.